# Bloquear Internet Explorer

Tags: php, html, navegador-de-internet

O IE tem um desempenho muito ruim no meu site.
Não Funcionam as Bordas Arredondada nos botões, e alguns outros defeitos.
Basicamente, o Internet Explorer está sendo Extinto pelo Mozilla Firefox e Pelo companheiro Chrome (Sem contar no Sucessor, o Microsoft Edge, Antes chamado de Spartan).

Eu Gostaria de um Código que detectasse o Navegador, e Se o usuário estivesse usando o IE, Redirecionasse para outra página. Nessa página, eu iria sugerir o Download do Mozilla ou do Chrome

Obrigado.

Comment: Talvez seja melhor utilizar algum *framework* como o [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) e tratar esses recursos ao invés de bloquear o acesso. - "Me force a trocar de navegador que nunca mais acesso o seu site, ou melhor, encontro um concorrente que dê suporte ao que eu utilizo".

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript

Para detetar o IE numa versão <= a 11 acho que podes usar:

```
if ("ActiveXObject" in window && document.documentMode <= 11){
    alert('é IE <= 11');
    // ou: window.location.href = "http://novo.url"
}
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsbin.com/dulisibuqa/1/

O `ActiveXObject` é uma propriedade só encontrada no IE e o `.documentMode` indica a versão do IE, e creio que é coerente com pequenas diferênças nas versões mais aintigas em_strict mode_, mas certamente `<=11`.

## PHP

```
preg_match('/MSIE (.*?);/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $matches);
if(count($matches)<2){
  preg_match('/Trident\/\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}; rv:([0-9]*)/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $matches);
}

if (count($matches) > 1 && $matches[1] <= 11){
    header('Location: http://novo.url'); die();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Para não perder o costume, procure utilizar Frameworks como Bootstrap que trabalham pensando na questão de compatibilidade, o que não faz você ter muito trabalho, e eventualmente lidar com essas coisas chatas, o pessoal já vai fazer isso pra você. Mas em todo caso, abaixo está o código.

```
if(preg_match('/MSIE/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']){
   die('Internet explorer bloqueado.');
}
```

**Para mais informações sobre as funções**:

- http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.server.php
- http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php

Comment: O Que eu gostaria é que ele redirecionasse para outra página.

Comment: Assim vai aparecer apenas um texto.

Comment: Ao invés de `die` coloque `window.location.href = "http://site.com/bloqueado";`.

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida isso é javascript... e a resposta está em PHP.

Comment: @HugoMarcelo No lugar de `die` coloque `header('Location: /pasta/pagina-escolhida.html'); exit;` :)

Comment: __Nota:__ este código pode também bloquear versões >11 do IE.

Answer (score 1):

A ideia de simplesmente tentar bloquear o Internet Explorer ou redirecionar o usuário para outra página talvez seja muito agressiva para usuários que ainda usam esse browser.

A melhor alternativa mesmo é seguir outro caminho: trabalhar com as limitações do browser e contorná-las sempre que possível. E assim como foi apontado no comentário à sua pergunta, pode-se usar o [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) para detectar se o browser suporta as features que você utiliza no seu site.

Tem também a ferramenta [Site scan](http://dev.modern.ie/tools/staticscan/) que ajuda a detectar possíveis problemas além de pontos a melhorar no seu site. Isso pode ajudar a fazer seu site a funcionar corretamente em diferentes browsers.

Seguem também alguns artigos que descrevem mais sobre [como fazer um site funcionar melhor no IE](http://talkitbr.com/2015/08/24/como-fazer-o-ie-exibir-melhor-o-meu-site/) e também [como fazer um site simplesmente funcionar em diferentes browsers](http://talkitbr.com/2015/08/27/criando-sites-que-simplesmente-funcionam/).